# angularJs - update range and number input simultaniously fails

Tags: angularjs, validation, input

I would like to change a range and an input box simultaneously using AngularJs but getting this error: "http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/ngModel/numfmt?p0=0.6"

I think the cause is the range updating the model with strings instead of numeric values but this doesn't get me closer to the solution.

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" ng-model="value" />
        <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" ng-model="value"/>
    </div>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 0.5;
});
</script>
```

How can I make the changes of the range applied on the input box without the error?

note: the obvious solution is to change the type of the input box to "text", but I would NOT like to allow non-numeric values there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseFloat:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="boltlandApp">
        <div ng-controller="controller">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" ng-model="value" />
            <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" ng-model="range"/>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('boltlandApp', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 0.5;
        $scope.range = 0.5;
        $scope.$watch('range', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.value = parseFloat(newVal);
        });
        $scope.$watch('value', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.range = newVal;
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but there seems to be a more simple workaround too.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a bug:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5892

A workaround is:

```
$scope.$watch('value', function() {
    $scope.value = parseFloat($scope.value);
});
```